# How the LWT- Light Weight Transaction is working when we use IF NOT EXIST?

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, partition, lwt

The question is that, When we use

```
    INSERT INTO USERS (login, email, name, login_count)        
    values ('jbellis', 'jbellis@datastax.com', 'Jonathan Ellis', 1)        
    IF NOT EXISTS
```

in **IF NOT EXIST** exactly which columns are compared together? primary key(partition-key + clustering-key)? or just partition-key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram of the 4 phases of LWT: http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-introduction-nantesjug/89

The original blog post is here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0

> exactly which columns are compare together? primary key? partition-key?

The whole primary key is checked on disk. In the example it is a simple primary key so it's also the partition key, e.g. **login** column