# Cassandra light weight transaction confusion

Tags: cassandra

I am a bit confused here in terms of terminology for light weight transactions. I am not sure why in most of the cassandra literature it says that it works only for a single partition.

Like when I use IF NOT EXISTS, IF EXISTS, it should apply to the whole primary key not just partition key as it says in this post as well [How the LWT- Light Weight Transaction is working when we use IF NOT EXIST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428976/how-the-lwt-light-weight-transaction-is-working-when-we-use-if-not-exist)

However, in the book Cassandra, the Definition Guide, I see this example

```
INSERT INTO reservation.reservations_by_confirmation 
(confirm_number,
hotel_id, start_date, end_date, room_number, guest_id) VALUES (
'RS2G0Z', 'NY456', '2020-06-08', '2020-06-10', 111, 1b4d86f4-ccff- 
4256-a63d-45c905df2677) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

This command checks to see if there is a record with the partition key, which for this table consists of the confirm_number. So let’s find out what happens when you execute this command a second time:

```
INSERT INTO reservation.reservations_by_confirmation 
(confirm_number,
hotel_id, start_date, end_date, room_number, guest_id) VALUES (
'RS2G0Z', 'NY456', '2020-06-08', '2020-06-10', 111, 1b4d86f4-ccff- 
4256-a63d-45c905df2677) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

In this case, the transaction fails, because there is already a reservation with the number “RS2G0Z,” and cqlsh helpfully echoes back a row containing a failure indication and the values you tried to enter.

[image]

Now my question is if I run, another query

```
INSERT INTO reservation.reservations_by_confirmation 
(confirm_number,
hotel_id, start_date, end_date, room_number, guest_id) VALUES (
'RS2G0Z', 'NY466', '2020-06-08', '2020-06-10', 111, 1b4d86f4-ccff- 
4256-a63d-45c905df2677) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

which is a different primary key but with the same partition key, it should succeed

So when the book says

```
This command checks to see if there is a record with the partition key
```

Isn't this a wrong statement? Please let me know if I am misinterpreting something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a error in the book, although diagram shows complex primary key, the table `reservation.reservations_by_confirmation` has very simple primary key - `confirm_number`, so in this case queries work as described in the text, and it doesn't allow to insert duplicate primary key.

When you see mentioning of the partition key in context of the LWT, this usually means that coordination happens between nodes that have replica of given partition...

Comment: Alex is correct, there is an error in the diagram. The second printing of the book will reflect a corrected diagram that matches the schema presented later in the chapter.